# Fail to mount on boot

Tags: 12.04, server, mount, filesystem, udev

I have just created a Ubuntu server and all is working well however at boot I receive the following error message which is causing problems. I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04

Here is the error any solution appreciated:

```
fsck from until-linux 2.20.1
mount: unkown filesystem type 'nosuid'
mountall: mount /dev/shm [284] terminated with status 32
mountall: Filesystem could not be mounted: /dev/shm
/dev/sda1: clean, 118954/24305664 files, 2148531/97219328 blocks
An error occurred while mounting /dev/shm
Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

EDIT:

when you click M for manual recovery it appears the error is thrown here

```
[   15.216401] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   16.014380] agpgart-ati 0000:00:00.0: unsupported Ati chipset [1002/5a331]
Filesystem check or mount failed
```

/etc/fstab/

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type> <options>     <dump>  <pass>
# proc            /proc           proc   nodev,noexec,nosuid 0     0
# / was on /dev/sdal during installation
UUID=1ee5176b-957842d1-955f-de689a5baeb8 /         ext4  errors=remount-ro 0  1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UDID=f5154c5b-6937-4fcc-8984-6129e74c35e9 none     swap  sw         0     0
tmpfs /dev/shm          defaults,boexec,nosuid    0   0
```

Its a real mess all system generated never been in here!

Comment: I get the same darn thing sometimes... Only with ubuntu though, restored different images and... still only ubuntu

Comment: Post your `/etc/fstab` file please. It most likely contains errors.

Comment: Ive added the /etc/fstab in the question ... I haven't added any of that code any help on tidying up greatly appreciated !!

Comment: See my edit ;) The top line is correct and you can copy/paste it over the bottom line you have in your fstab :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nosuid` is an option for mounting partitions/discs and options are the next column after the filesystem type.

`/dev/shm` is a temporary file storage filesystem. You probably added this yourself to `/etc/fstab`? Lines inside `/etc/fstab` need to be similar to this lay-out (the device names will probably be UUIDs):

```
# device name   mount point     fs-type      options           dump-freq pass-num
LABEL=/         /               ext4         defaults           1         1
/dev/sda6       swap            swap         defaults           0         0
none            /dev/pts        devpts       gid=5,mode=620     0         0
none            /proc           proc         defaults           0         0
none            /dev/shm        tmpfs        defaults           0         0
```

The last line is a possible similar line as you will need.  Your `/etc/fstab` will have a line related to `/dev/shm` with `nosuid` in the `fs-type` column. Of course that is an invalid filesystem so Ubuntu can not mount the disc.

Change it to something similar as in my example by dropping to command line and

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

and correct the line matching `/dev/shm`.

---

See the difference?

```
# device name   mount point     fs-type      options           dump-freq pass-num
none            /dev/shm        tmpfs        defaults           0         0

tmpfs           /dev/shm        defaults,boexec,nosuid    0     0
```

It is not even close to being correct ;)